# Where to type HTML code in Oracle APEX?

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a desktop application in ORACLE APEX called Book Loan.
It has a Login page, Home Page, Book List Page and Create/Edit Loan Page.
The home page is blank.
Therefore, I want to add an image on the center of the home page.

For that I have the following HTML code.

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#book.jpg" alt="image">
```

To my understanding, the above piece of HTML code should be written in Static Content under the Regions Section which is on the bottom panel of the page.

What I did was I right clicked on Static Content and after right clicking on Static Content, I chose Add To Content Body.

However, on the right hand side panel, I don't know where to add the html code.

Shall I type my html code in "Text" box under "Source" section ?
OR
Shall  I type my html code in "Header Text" box or "Footer Text" box under "Header and Footer" section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of those would work, but Source is the usual place for such code.

Another way, writing no HTML at all, would be to create a Display Image item in the new region, with `#APP_IMAGES#book.jpg` as the item value.